# Reading a certain pixels color from a window

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently reading a certain pixels color from a process window like this:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
private static extern int BitBlt(IntPtr srchDc, int srcX, int srcY, int srcW, 
                         int srcH, IntPtr desthDc, int destX, int destY, int op);

public static Color GetPixel(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y)
{
    var screenPixel = new Bitmap(1, 1);

    using (Graphics gdest = Graphics.FromImage(screenPixel))
    {
        using (Graphics gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd(
                                            MemoryHandler.GetMainWindowHandle()))
        {
            IntPtr hsrcdc = gsrc.GetHdc();
            IntPtr hdc = gdest.GetHdc();
            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 1, 1, hsrcdc, x, y, 
                                             (int)CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            gdest.ReleaseHdc();
            gsrc.ReleaseHdc();
        }
    }

    return screenPixel.GetPixel(0, 0);
}
```

---

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern COLORREF GetPixel(IntPtr hdc, int nXPos, int nYPos);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]


public struct COLORREF
{
    public uint ColorDWORD;

    public COLORREF(System.Drawing.Color color)
    {
        ColorDWORD = (uint)color.R + (((uint)color.G) << 8) + 
                                     (((uint)color.B) << 16);
    }

    public System.Drawing.Color GetColor()
    {
        return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb((int)(0x000000FFU & ColorDWORD),
    (int)(0x0000FF00U & ColorDWORD) >> 8, (int)(0x00FF0000U & ColorDWORD) >> 16);
    }

    public void SetColor(System.Drawing.Color color)
    {
        ColorDWORD = (uint)color.R + (((uint)color.G) << 8)
                            + (((uint)color.B) << 16);
    }
}
```

It seems to be working.

I would like to know if I'm disposing everything that I use correctly to avoid memory leaks. If I inspect my app in the task manager I notice that the memory use is increasing a bit for each time i fetch a pixel, but I suppose the garbage collector will kick in when it's supposed to?

Also, is there any obvious "better" way of doing this?

Comment: you're not disposing `screenPixel`, though I doubt that is the issue, unless you're calling this a whole lot of times.

Comment: @Rotem Thanks for the input. Guess I might as well do it

Comment: You could just [pinvoke GetPixel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Graphics.CopyFromScreen() avoids all pinvoke.

Comment: @HansPassant Please have a look at my update. Is this what you are referring to? I'm only getting a white (255,255,255) pixel using this.